# $scope data convert to date format

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to convert `$scope` data to date format?

```
{{book.take_time | date: 'HH:mm'}}

$http.get("../api/book.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.book = response.data;
});
```

inside book have `book_id`, `book_name`, `take_time` 
how to convert take_time to date format?

Comment: What is take time currently? is an Unix timestamp?

Comment: now string format like this 03:25:30.

Comment: If that is the format, you have an already converted time. It seems to me you want to skip the seconds, and only keep the hours and minutes. You could do a substring in order to fix that (if all your times are formatted the same), e.g. `var converted = book.take_time.substring(0,6)`

Comment: If i have convert to this format 3:25 AM how can i do?

Comment: date filter only works with date type objects. Please see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). Try passing the original date object to the filter instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The input $scope.book is actually an array of books. Pl refer authors comments.

This is a rather crude way of doing it, but you can try something like this:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="value in books">    
    {{value.take_time | date: 'shortTime'}} 
</p>

$http.get("../api/book.php").then(function(response) {
      $scope.book = response.data;

      angular.forEach($scope.book, function(value, key) {

        var res = value.take_time.split(":");
        //Assuming time is in hh:mm:ss format
        var date = new Date();
        date.setMinutes(res[1]);
        date.setHours(res[0]);

        value.take_time = date;
      });



});
```

See a sample of it working here: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBB8M1JMPUX5

Comment: [{"book_id":"161","book_name”:”C++”,”take_time”:”13.50.43”},{"book_id":"162”,”book_name”:”Ruby”,”take_time”:”14.27.02”}]

Comment: my scope book will be like this

Comment: change the script accordingly then..include a for loop. The above ans works assuming $scope.book is something like this {"book_id":"161","book_name”:”C++”,”take_time”:”13.50.43”}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132002/discussion-between-koder23-and-user2534252).

Answer (score 1):

Use Moment.js to convert time format

```
moment($scope.data[0].take_time).format('HH:mm')
```

or if you have array then

```
angular.forEach($scope.data,function(value,key){value.take_time = moment(value.take_time).format('HH:mm')});
```

below is link for that js

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you can try for "shortTime" date format

> 'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' for en_US locale (e.g. 12:05 PM)

for details--https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date